# Removing history of wireless connections?

Tags: wireless-networking, history, connection

How can I remove the history of wireless connections?

Comment: If you don't mind telling us which operating system you're using ... :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP you can delete wireless networks in the Wireless Network Connection properties:

[image]

In Vista/7: Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Manage Wireless Networks

Right click on a network and select Remove.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write pretty much the same as Molly, but also I recommend [Nirsoft Wireless Key View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html), you will be able to easily view and delete saved Wireless passwords for all versions of Windows.